# Android: Implementing Sliding Behavior Using ViewPager or Alternatives

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

To sum my entire dilemma, I essentially want to create sliding tabs similar to the new Facebook app.

I know I can achieve sliding behavior using a **ViewPager** and populating each tab with **Fragment**. `Using a fragment is my limitation`.

```
---------------------------
|       Action Bar        |
---------------------------
|    Tab1    |    Tab2    |
---------------------------
|                         |
|   Needs to contain      |
|   multiple fragments    |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
---------------------------
```

When one tab is selected, it needs to contain multiple fragments. I assume that each post in the Facebook app is an individual fragment so I need similar behavior.

Is there a way I can achieve this behavior? Or in the Facebook app, is each page an Activity and when they slide, the only slide the lower portion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I know you can use fragments inside fragments, in fact fragments themselves have a fragment manager (try using getChildFragmentManager())

But what I would personally do, is this

a) Have the Wall fragment be a scrollview with a vertical linear layout in it

b) Create a layout file with the layout of how a post should look like

c) Inflate the layout created in b) then add it to the main Wall layout for each Post you wish to show